# Wifi driver not working

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, drivers

I reinstalled my laptop from windows 8 to windows 7. All the drivers were installed correctly but when I try to install wifi driver it says: "The device may not be present or could have been ejected/unplugged from the system. Insert or Reinsert Now.". With windows 8 the wifi worked well... I have ASUS N56VJ

Answer (score -1):

do you find it in device manager?
http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/a/device-manager-windows-8.htm

and it does sound like you have installed wrong driver, what kind of wifi card is it? atheros, broadcom, intel?

Comment: No its not in device manager. it is Qualcomm Atheros.